# Using both /etc/postfix/virtual *and* /etc/aliases with Postfix

Tags: email, postfix

I have a /etc/postfix/virtual file set up to alias mail to different domains to the right local user, however I also want to use /etc/aliases to alias certain local users (mostly nobody and postmaster to root) -- I have:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

But it seems to be ignoring the /etc/aliases (I have   nobody: root   but mail to nobody@localhost still goes to /var/mail/nobody)

Comment: Did you use postmap after editing the aliases file?

Comment: I used it on the virtual file... do I also need to call it on the aliases file?

Comment: Running postmap on /etc/aliases gives a bunch of warnings and running postalias has no effect

Comment: paste the results of postconf (obscure the things you want hidden). See if it matches what you think it should...  If not maybe this will help.

Comment: postconf output (hostnames redacted) : http://pastie.org/1273446

Answer (score 1):

Q: Did you run `newaliases` after changing the `/etc/aliases/` file?
A: you say “yes”.

Q: Do you have similar output for the following command?

```
# file /etc/aliases*
/etc/aliases:    ASCII text
/etc/aliases.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)
```

Comment: Just tried running postmap /etc/aliases followed by newaliases and then reloading postfix... no effect.

Comment: $ file /etc/aliases*
/etc/aliases:    ASCII text
/etc/aliases.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)

Comment: Could the problem have something to do with me using procmail for delivery?  I have: mailbox_command = procmail -a $EXTENSION